# Count or flag number of times dataframe column reaches a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I'm looking to do to is add a new column that essentially 'flags' if a condition is met in a separate column - where if the next value < previous value then flag it. For simplicity lets go with 1 (yes) and 0 (no). Example below:

DF_original:

```
Col1 
  4
  5
  3
  9
  12
  11
  15
```

DF_desired:

```
Col1      Col_flag
  4           0
  5           0
  3           1
  9           0
  12          0
  11          1
  15          0
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `df.Col1.diff().le(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `np.where()` and `diff()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[4,5,3,9,12,11,15]})
df['Col2'] = np.where(df['col1'].diff() < 0,1,0)
```

This would output:

```
   col1  Col2
0     4     0
1     5     0
2     3     1
3     9     0
4    12     0
5    11     1
6    15     0
```

Comment: in the 'diff' statement what do the '0,1,0' numbers represent?

Comment: We're using `np.where()` the condition is `df['col1'].diff() < 0` if true `1`, if false `0`. The `1` and `0` are the values to be returned when the condition is true or false respectively.